# QT open a form(.ui) from main form by button push

Tags: c++, qt

I have searched many forums to solve this problem so please don't just link a forum.

I have my main.ui that is loaded at the start. it's header

```
using namespace Ui;
class main: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    void AddPlayer();

public:
    main(QWidget *parent = 0);
   ~main();

private:
    Ui::mainClass ui;
    Ui::FormPla uiPlayer;//the name of the form i want to open
};
```

Then i have the main.cpp

```
main::main(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
     ui.setupUi(this);
     connect(ui.mainBtnPla, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(AddPlayer()));
}
main::~main()
{
}
void FinalYearProject::AddPlayer() 
{
    //code to open player.ui

    //formPla *obj;
    //obj = new formPla();
    //obj->show(); //i tried this but show wasnt a member of ui::player

}
```

player.ui doesnt have a .h or .cpp. I dont know if this affects this. I just want to be able open the form.

Answer (score 0):

ui generated classes cannot be used without a `QWidget` class loading them.

You must create a separate `QWidget` base class (Player), loading `Ui::FormPla` and later create an instance of this class to show the `Ui::FormPla` on screen.

Comment: I've added the class 

    `class player : public QWidget
    {
     Q_OBJECT

    public:
     player(QWidget *parent = 0);
     ~player();

    private:
     Ui::formPla ui;
    };`

    `player::player(QWidget *parent)
 : QWidget(parent)
    {
 ui.setupUi(this);
 
    }

    player::~player()
    {
    //delete ui; 
    }`

a form appears for a short amount of time then goes.


    `void main::AddPlayer() {
 
 player *obj;
 obj->show();
 
    }`

Comment: If player object should be child of your main widget, you must add it to the main widget's layout. If it is meant to be a separate dialog, then you need to attach it to a 'QDialog' and use 'QDialog::exec()'. You can also directly have player derive from 'QDialog' and then call 'obj->exec()' instead of 'obj->show()'